# Confounded by XPath

Tags: html, xpath

When it comes to indexing in XPath, I feel like I'm missing something here.

If I have two table tags in an HTML document, and within the Chrome console I type

```
$x("//table[1]");
```

, I expect to get the first table tag on the page.

Instead, I get a list containing both table tags.  I suspected it might have something to do with using

```
//
```

but using an absolute XPath expression yielded the same results.

I think this is a pretty simple misunderstanding, but I'm not seeing it when reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//table[1]` returns all tables that are  the first table child of their respective parents.

To get the first table use `/descendant::table[1]` or in XPath 2.0 `(//table)[1]`.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#abbrev) it is in the standard:

> The path expression //para[1] does not mean the same as the path expression /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their respective parents.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(//table)[1]
```

i.e. the first of all the tables.